# How to deeplink electronjs apps in development and production?

Tags: javascript, electron, deep-linking

I've been trying to deeplink an electronjs app and I have found this solution: https://github.com/oikonomopo/electron-deep-linking-mac-win

Also, wanted to try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-deeplink
but it doesn't even seem to get installed

[image: Deeplink ElectronJS]

But this works only on Mac and Windows, but also, this only works on Production ( After generating EXE/DMG and installing it ), it doesn't work while developing. Now I only want 2 things:

1. Being able to test deeplinking while developing the app ( cause, generating the distributable does take a good amount of time everytime after changing some codes )
2. Being able to deeplink in Linux ( Not so important for now at least )

Any way to do these? thanks